# Error displaying apostrophes in ASCII

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm making a custom zsh theme for when you open up your terminal. I'm not that new to using oh-my-zsh but I am new to zsh documentation.

Here's what I'm having problems with:

```
wolf='               
           .-'''''-.
         .'         `.
        :             :
       :               :
       :      _/|      :
        :   =/_/      :
         `._/ |     .'
      (   /  ,|...-'
       \_/^\/||__
    _/~  `""~`"` \_
 __/  -'/  `-._ `\_\__
/     /-'`  `\   \  \-.\\

'


print -P $wolf
```

When I try it in terminal I get two errors:

1. /Users/User/.oh-my-zsh/themes/wolf.zsh-theme:4: no such file or directory: .         `.\n            :             :\n           :               :\n           :      _/|      :\n            :   =/_/      :\n`._/ |
2. /Users/User/.oh-my-zsh/themes/wolf.zsh-theme:31: parse error near `\n

I'm guessing that these errors have to do with the apostrophes in the ASCII art.

Comment: `set -x` and `set -v` are your friends. But almost certainly you need to escape shell specific metacharacters, and you need to know how many levels of escaping you need. I'm not sure how much Oh My Zsh needs when it sources the startup file(s), so not an answer. But start with a single level of escaping and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here (as [jdv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1531971) noted in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45150560/i-need-help-making-a-custom-zsh-theme#comment77270575_45150560)) is quoting.

In `zsh`:

- it is not possible to use single-quotes (`'`) withing single-quoted text. Any text within two single-quotes is taken verbatim, no additional quoting is possible. Single quotes can only be quoted with a preceding backslash or inside double quotes.
- Within double-quotes (`"`) backticks (`` ` ``), dollar signs (`$`) and backslashes (`\`) are treated specially, and need to be quoted with a preceding backslash.

As quite a lot of these characters appear in your ASCII-art, you have to make sure, that they are all quoted properly.

Additionally, you use the builtin `print`, which by default also interprets `\` as escape character.

There are two basic solutions:

- Fully quote the string and use `print -r` or `echo -E` to print the text. In both cases the parameter disables escape sequence handling.

  The easiest way to achieve full quoting is probably to keep the surrounding single-quotes and replace any `'` within with `'\''`. At every occurrence this closes the previous single-quoted text, adds a quoted single-quote and starts a new single-quoted text. Any other special character is then quoted within single quotes.

  ```
  wolf='               
             .-'\'''\'''\'''\'''\''-.
           .'\''         `.
          :             :
         :               :
         :      _/|      :
          :   =/_/      :
           `._/ |     .'\''
        (   /  ,|...-'\''
         \_/^\/||__
      _/~  `""~`"` \_
   __/  -'\''/  `-._ `\_\__
  /     /-'\''`  `\   \  \-.\\

  '
  print -r $wolf
  ```
- Use a *here-document* with `cat` to avoid the whole quoting issue:

  ```
  cat <<'END'
             .-'''''-.
           .'         `.
          :             :
         :               :
         :      _/|      :
          :   =/_/      :
           `._/ |     .'
        (   /  ,|...-'
         \_/^\/||__
      _/~  `""~`"` \_
   __/  -'/  `-._ `\_\__
  /     /-'`  `\   \  \-.\\

  END
  ```

  Note the single quotes around `'END'`. This needs to be done in order to disable parameter substitution (`$FOO`) and command substitution (`$(command)` or `` `command` ``) inside the here-document.